# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook-sdk-3.1

Hello I am currently working on an IOS app in xcode 6. I am getting the following error when archiving the application. It runs successfully when built on the emulator. After further inspection I've found this specific error message while compiling each piece of code step-by-step in the terminal.

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBLoginView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBProfilePictureView", referenced from:
     objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You are missing armv7 in your target settings in "Architectures" and "Valid Architectures". Actually  facebook library was not build for armv7,
what is why you are getting this error from linker.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should go to your project settings, then your target and ensure you set the Architectures and Valid Architectures to what you see in the below image, the first one is selectable through Xcode while you should ensure you set the second one manually.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while runnning the project.

1. Go to Build settings -- > Build architecture only
   to set

> Debug - YES
>
> Release - NO

2. Add --> Other linker flag: `- objc, -lc++, $(inherited)`

clean and run the project. It was fixed for me !